# Нужна помощь со скриптом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я совсем ничего не понимаю в js. Нашел скрипт который выводит картинки в **случайном** порядке и он отлично работает. Но появилась необходимость на некоторых страницах выводить картинки **по порядку**. Помогите, пожалуйста, подправить скрипт.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
                var current = 0,

                    $imgs = jQuery('#exercise .cbk');
                imgAmount = $imgs.length;

                $($imgs.css('position', 'relative').hide().get(0)).show();
                window.setInterval(swapImages, getUrlVars()["speed"]);
                function swapImages() {

                    var $currentImg = $('.cbk:visible');

                    var $nextImg = $('.cbk:hidden').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.cbk:hidden').length));
                        speed = 0;
                    $currentImg.fadeOut(speed);
                    $nextImg.fadeIn(speed);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

html:

```
         <div id="exercise">
            <div class="cbk">
              <img src="images/00.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="cbk">
              <img src="images/01.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="cbk">
              <img src="images/02.jpg"  />
            </div>
            <div class="cbk">
              <img src="images/03.jpg"  />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Добавь двойной слеш (//) перед window.setInterval(swapImages, getUrlVars()["speed"]);

Что бы было //window.setInterval(swapImages, getUrlVars()["speed"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените строку:

```
var $nextImg = $('.cbk:hidden').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.cbk:hidden').length));
```

На

```
var $nextImg = $('.cbk:visible + .cbk').get(0) ? $('.cbk:visible + .cbk') : $('.cbk').eq(0);
```